# Domain Name language negotiation and mobile prefix m

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a question regarding the domain name language negotiation.

I have 3 languages and the following domains:

- de.domain.com
- en.domain.com
- fr.domain.com

When I set this as the domains for each language and use the domain name language negotiation everything works as expected.

My problem is that I have an adaptive mobile theme and I have to use following domains for that:

- m.de.domain.com
- m.en.domain.com
- m.fr.domain.com

How can I achieve that those urls point to the correct language (de, en, fr). Now, all point to the default language (de).

Any help?

Comment: Just curious - why m prefix? Can't you detect from http headers if user is on mobile? Can't your theme hide things based on actual screen it gets displayed on?

Comment: In my oppinion its not a good thing to have different content served from the same url. think about a caching in front of the web server (varnish for example).

Comment: That's some valid point all right. On the other hand current mobile devices can usually accept normal page and you can do the most of small-screen logic in CSS with [media set to handheld](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp).

Comment: That's totally true. But the customer has preferred adaptive over responsive for this project. So i have to deal with that now. Responsive would make my live easier at all ;)

Comment: can you make it `de.m.` instead of `m.de.`? If it's technically impossible / not easy, it's a shame both mechanisms insist on using first part for detection.

Comment: Hmm, what would that change ? de.m or m.de, both are different domains. Or what do you think ?

Comment: Language recognition looks on first part of a domain, right? so if you could put `.de` as first part, it would be properly recognized as language prefix, no matter if there is `.m` after it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Language Negotiation API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!language.inc/group/language_negotiation/7), specifically [hook_language_negotiation_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_negotiation_info_alter/7).  With this hook, you can replace the default URL based language negotiation callback function with one that respects the `m.` prefix.

Something like this should get you started.

```
function mymodule_language_negotiation_info_alter(&$negotiation_info) {
  // Replace the core function with our own function.
  module_load_include('language', 'inc', 'language.negotiation');
  $negotiation_info[LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_URL]['callbacks']['language'] = 'mymodule_from_url';
  $negotiation_info[LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_URL]['file'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.module';
}

function mymodule_from_url($languages) {
    // Your version of locale_language_from_url() that ignores the m. prefix.
}
```

For reference, the core function that handles language negotiation based on URL is [locale_language_from_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!locale.inc/function/locale_language_from_url/7).

Comment: Thank you zroger. I think this way i can achieve my goal :)